# OpenCV feature matching parallel processing

Tags: c++, opencv

The images I am matching have this property: A correctly matched keypoint pair should have the same(or very close) y-coordinate value.
 [Kind of like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI9s5.png).

To speed up the program and improve accuracy. I cut both images into 12 horizontal stripes and then do the feature matching.

The goal is to obtain the keypoint information(coordinate).

It looks like this:

```
void featureMatching(Mat &img1, Mat &img2, vector<KeyPoint> &keypoints_1,
                 vector<KeyPoint> &keypoints_2) {
    // store the matched keypoint pairs into keypoints_1 and keypoints_2.
}

void feature_blocks(Mat &img_l, Mat &img_r, vector<KeyPoint> &keypoints_l,
                 vector<KeyPoint> &keypoints_r, int num_block) {
    Mat block_l, block_r;
    Mat temp_block;
    vector<Mat> mat_blocks;
    vector<KeyPoint> temp_keypoints_l, temp_keypoints_r;
    Mat concated_block;

    int block_width, bloch_height;
    block_width = img_l.cols;
    block_height = int(img_l.rows / num_block);

    for (int i = 0, coor_y = 0; i < num_block; i++, coor_y += block_height) {
        if (i == num_block - 1)
            block_height += img_l.rows % num_block;
        block_l = img_l(Rect(0, coor_y, block_width, bloch_height));
        block_r = img_r(Rect(0, coor_y, block_width, bloch_height));
        if (DEBUG) {
            cout << "----- block " << i << " ----- " << endl;
        }
        temp_keypoints_l.clear();
        temp_keypoints_r.clear();
        featureMatching(block_l, block_r, temp_keypoints_l, temp_keypoints_r);
        keypoints_l.insert(end(keypoints_l), begin(temp_keypoints_l),
                           end(temp_keypoints_l));
        keypoints_r.insert(end(keypoints_r), begin(temp_keypoints_r),
                           end(temp_keypoints_r));
    }
}

int main() {
    ...
    img1 = imread("test1.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    img2 = imread("test2.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoint1, keypoint2;
    feature_blocks(img1, img2, keypoint1, keypoint2, 12);

}
```

As long as keypoint1[i] corresponds to keypoint2[i], the keypoint order in keypoint1 and keypoint2 doesn't matter. Is there an easy way parallelize the for loop in feature_blocks?

I read [the tutorial in OpenCV's document](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html), but I just don't know how to implement it. That is, I don't know how to make each thread handle an image block.

**EDIT**

I use OpenMP by the recommendation of Warpstar22.
It works!

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < num_block; i++) {
        int block_height = int(img_l.rows / num_block);
        int coor_y = block_height * i;

        if (i == num_block - 1)
            block_height += img_l.rows % num_block;

        Mat block_l, block_r;
        block_l = img_l(Rect(0, coor_y, block_width, block_height));
        block_r = img_r(Rect(0, coor_y, block_width, block_height));
        if (DEBUG) {
            cout << "----- block " << i << " ----- " << endl;
        }

        vector<KeyPoint> temp_keypoints_l, temp_keypoints_r;
        featureMatching(block_l, block_r, temp_keypoints_l, temp_keypoints_r,
                    coor_y);

        #pragma omp critical
        keypoints_l.insert(end(keypoints_l), begin(temp_keypoints_l),
                           end(temp_keypoints_l));
        #pragma omp critical
        keypoints_r.insert(end(keypoints_r), begin(temp_keypoints_r),
                           end(temp_keypoints_r));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have an easier time using OpenMP. OpenMP can be real easy to integrate. I've used it plenty when I make an algorithm and find it slow. If you're trying to parallelize the loop, then you can add the line `#pragma omp parallel for` above your for loop statement. You will then have to compile with `-fopenmp`. Here is a [link](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs3225-GIS/fall16/Lectures/openmp.html) to a simple tutorial on OpenMP.

Alternatively, I would imagine OpenCV has already optimized the processing with parallel processing when running their feature descriptor functions. I'm not sure of that but I know when building there is a flag for parallel processing support you need to make sure is enabled. Also,the parallel_for function doesn't work if you don't have that either.